# How To Create 10 Blank Text Files with specific names as name Given in Input Textbox?

Tags: text, basic

I am currently using `Vb Code` to create a Blank Text File which has `Name` as text input in `textbox1 =` specifies name of person and `textbox2 =` specifies current date.

#### Code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\Users\Sandip\Desktop\asasasasa\" & TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text & ".txt"

    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

---

I have a list of 10 people and want to create 10 blank text files with a specific name and date as input to the textbox.

Example:

1. Person name  & Date    = created text file Person name Date.txt
2. ross        13Oct2016  =   ross13Oct2016.txt
3. Sam         13Oct2016  =   sam13Oct2016.txt
4. Ben         13Oct2016  =   Ben13Oct2016.txt

Names of people are constant and I have to change the date everyday.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

i didn't understand to 100% what you want to do but i think this should help

```
Dim txt As TextBox
    For i = 1 To 10
        txt = New TextBox
        txt.Location = New Point(25 * i, 50)
        txt.Name = filepath
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. For better understanding i have added image-"For Example Image". Please see the Image!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with myStreamWriter.
Code is-

```
    Dim Save As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim myStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label3.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label4.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label5.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label7.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label8.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label9.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label10.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label15.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label16.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)
    myStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\" & Label17.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True)

    myStreamWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

`